# Appending string in multi-dimensional array to .csv file c#

Tags: c#, arrays, csv

I have a multi-dimensional array and I want to write it into a .csv and when it displays in Excel I want it to be in the same matrix-esque order.

```
        string[,] output = new string[,] { {"n=", "128", "256", "512", "1024", "2048", "4096", "8192", "16384", "32768", "65536", "131072", "262144", "524288", "1048576", "2097152", "4194304", "8388608"},
                                           { "Selection", timeSelection128, timeSelection256, timeSelection512, timeSelection1024, timeSelection2048, timeSelection4096, timeSelection8192, timeSelection16384, timeSelection32768, timeSelection65536, timeSelection131072, timeSelection262144, timeSelection524288, timeSelection1048576, timeSelection2097152, timeSelection4194304, timeSelection8388608 },
                                           { "Insertion", timeInsertion128, timeInsertion256, timeInsertion512, timeInsertion1024, timeInsertion2048, timeInsertion4096, timeInsertion8192, timeInsertion16384, timeInsertion32768, timeInsertion65536, timeInsertion131072, timeInsertion262144, timeInsertion524288, timeInsertion1048576, timeInsertion2097152, timeInsertion4194304, timeInsertion8388608 },
                                           { "Merge", timeMerge128, timeMerge256, timeMerge512, timeMerge1024, timeMerge2048, timeMerge4096, timeMerge8192, timeMerge16384, timeMerge32768, timeMerge65536, timeMerge131072, timeMerge262144, timeMerge524288, timeMerge1048576, timeMerge2097152, timeMerge4194304, timeMerge8388608 },
                                           { "Quick", timeQuick128, timeQuick256, timeQuick512, timeQuick1024, timeQuick2048, timeQuick4096, timeQuick8192, timeQuick16384, timeQuick32768, timeQuick65536, timeQuick131072, timeQuick262144, timeQuick524288, timeQuick1048576, timeQuick2097152, timeQuick4194304, timeQuick8388608 } };`
```

That's my multi-dimensional array and now I'm doing something like this... [5x18]

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 18; y++)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, output[x,y]));
            }
            File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
        }
```

But this is just giving me an excel file with everything in the first column one after the other. I need each row in the array to be a row in Excel, etc.

Answer (score 0):

well, check the output file VS the one generated with excel and see the differences. If there are no visual differences, then you might be try and use `sb.Append(string.Concat("bla", "\r\n")).`

Answer (score 0):

`String.Join` itself joins a *list of strings* already. No need for a loop. This should do:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
    sb.AppendLine(String.Join(delimiter, output[x]));

File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

---

You are probably right - you can not use the above code on a multi-dimensional array as I thought.

Then you have to do it manually:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()
for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    StringBuilder lineBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int y = 0; y < 18; y++)
    {
        if (lineBuilder.Count > 0)
            lineBuilder.Append(delimiter);
        lineBuilder.Append(output[x,y]);
    }

    sb.AppendLine(lineBuilder);
}

File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: It doesn't like that because it's the wrong number of indices into the multi-dimensional matrix.

Comment: Will change my answer.